# Add string to selected column values

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing two columns -

```
   col1    col2
   -------------
   1       apple   
   2       bag   
   3       car   
   4       deal   
   5       eel
```

I want to add string characters to specific values like -

```
    col1    col2  
    -------------   
    1        a_0pple    
    2        bag    
    3        c_0ar    
    4        d_0eal    
    5        eel
```

I used -
`df_srt['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str).str[:1] + '_0' + df['col2'].astype(str).str[1:]`

I get is -

```
    col1    col2   
    -------------     
    1       a_0pple    
    2       b_0ag    
    3       c_0ar    
    4       d_0eal    
    5       e_0el
```

How can i transform the code to work on specific column values.

Comment: "I want to add to specific values": How do you decide these values? Your code applies it to all values because you never specify the condition based on which to decide whether or not to modify the value.

Answer (score 0):

use the .apply() method of a DataFrame or Series. this allows you to apply a function itemwise to the object. you can use an existing function, define your own and pass it to apply, or for simple cases like this one create it in a lambda. the following achieves what you already have above

`df.col2.apply(lambda x: ''.join([x[0], '_0', x[1:]]))`

all you need to do is add some condition

`df.col2.apply(lambda x: ''.join([x[0], '_0', x[1:]]) if x[0] in ['a', 'c', 'd'] else x)`